# Hosted javascript libraries

Tags: javascript

Besides [Google Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) what other services are there for hosted javascript libraries?

Please only list trusted sources, not some unknown third party.

Answer (score 1):

Microsofts CDN
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx

Answer (score 1):

Before you go in search of hosted JavaScript libraries, you should consider the fact that any JavaScript that you include in your web page runs within the context of your domain and can access any data rendered on the web page or that the user can normally access on your domain. Using Google's hosted JavaScript is fine, but if its some third party you never have heard of, you might want to think twice.

Perhaps it would be better to search for high-quality JavaScript libraries and download your own copy that you maintain within your domain on your own servers (and can audit for security purposes)?

Out of curiosity... what specific functionality are you looking for?

Comment: That's a given, but I'll add a note to my answer to explain. And sorry to be pedantic but this should've been a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Yahoo YUI (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) though I believe they only host YUI itself.  Make sure you pay attention to Michael Safyan's answer, too - who you're willing to trust with your users' code should be a carefully made decision.  Beyond that, if you're looking for generic JS hosting you should make sure you really **need** it - a minified version of jQuery or MooTools is incredibly tiny, and shouldn't make any real difference either to your server's CPU usage or bandwidth expenditure.

It also doesn't meaningfully affect the maintainability of your HTML or JS, and it introduces another point of failure in your implementation.